# Angular Check if array is defined during interpolation

Tags: angular

I am now using the `?` operator to check if an object exists when interpolating the values in my html. For example:

```
<input type="text" class="" name="iptname" value="{{object?.property}}" #iptname>
```

This works. But how to check `?` with an array. The below code throughs me an error saying `array` is undefined.

```
<input type="text" class="" name="iptname" value="{{object?.array[arrayindex].property}}" #iptname>
```

**My Failed Attempt**

```
<input type="text" class="" name="iptname" value="{{object?.array?[arrayindex].property}}" #iptname>
```

But this does not work. So how can I interpolate through arrays keeping the array variable optional?

Comment: Stackblitz repro would be helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="text" class="" name="iptname" [attr.value]="object?.array[arrayindex]?.property" #iptname>
```